# Autoupdating NSManagedObject property modification timestamp

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject, key-value-observing

I have an `NSManagedObject` with two properties:

```
NSNumber *score;
NSDate *score_timestamp;
```

I want my `score_timestamp` field to be updated each time I update `score`.

I obviously cannot use `-willSave` method as my context is saved occasionally, and `score_timestamp` won't be up to date. So I should either override `-setScore:` or setup my managed object as a key-value observer for its own `score` field.

The `-setScore:` solution seems easy:

```
- (void) setScore:(NSNumber *)score
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"score"];
    [self setPrimitiveScore:score];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"score"];

    self.score_timestamp = [NSDate date];
}
```

Are there any caveats in doing things that way? Or I should use a KVO solution?

**Update**

So far I've received two responses that my code will not work through `setValue: forKey:` and I'm still waiting for example. Naive calling `[(NSManagedObject *)myObject setValue:value forKey:@"score"]` calls my setter all the same.

So if I switch to KVO solution, should I `addObserver:` in all `awake` methods and remove it in `willTurnIntoFault`? Or that's not that simple?

Comment: Seriously, both answerers stating that setValue... wont work are wrong. You can test this yourself quite trivially by putting a breakpoint in your accessor, then changing the value using setValue.

Comment: @jrturton I've tested it already, it surely gets called. But I'm not a Core Data expert to be sure if there's another way of changing my property without accessor. I mean the way to be used occasionally in real code.

Comment: Nope. All core data calls will go through your setter (possibly via setValueForKey first). It's part of the encapsulation principle. You could have some freaky direct access to the ivar but this would have to be something you'd written yourself which would probably also break the managed object context. You wouldn't do that to yourself, would you?

Comment: @jrturton Yeah, that's a great explanation! I was thinking of the same from the beginning (otherwise I'd immediately start with KVO), but you see, some people say that's not correct :) It would be great if you create an answer for me to mark it.

Comment: @jrturton Sorry, seems I'm loosing attention and I definitely need to sleep. I've just found that I added a warning to your legit answer (missed the moment you've edited it), so I removed my note. Let's do it in the following way: I can't trust myself enough to take a decision now so I'll come back to my question tomorrow morning :) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation in your question is fine. Any KVC attempt to update your value will also go through the setter method (`setValue: forKey:` simply searches for an accessor method matching `setKey`, see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html) for details).

Comment: I see "You must not override this method" in `NSManagedObject -didChangeValue:` documentation!

Comment: I've edited your answer because it began to get +1s while being dangerous. Thank you for your effort to help me, to express my gratitude I've +1ed some of your answers to other questions (they are of great help too :)

Comment: I don't think it got any upvotes in its previous version, but fair enough. It's a valid edit!

Comment: @iHunter: You just added the warning, and [now you're proposing to remove it](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/170968)? What's going on here? If the warning is valid, it should stay there.

Comment: I redoed my edit, it became irrelevant as you've updated your answer.

Comment: @CodyGray jrturton has updated his answer, the warning is not relevant anymore. And I'm too asleep to understand what's happening, so I may be completely missing the point :)

Comment: @iHunter: No, I see what happened. Your suggested edit got crossed just as jrturton was editing his original answer. Should be all straightened out now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

```
[objectWithArray addObserver:self 
                  forKeyPath:@"score"
                     options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew 
                     context:nil];
```

Then to observe it:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                      ofObject:(id)object 
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change 
                       context:(void *)context 
{
    //Check if [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] is equal to "score" 
    //and update the score_timestamp appropriately
}
```

You should register for the notification when you awake from fetch and unregister when you fault, I believe.

Comment: Yeah, KVO is a good solution here, but I don't see a problem in my existing code. I suspect setting another property in setter is not a good idea, but I want to know why, because I see it works :)

Comment: If you can guarantee that your code will only ever use the dynamically generated getter/setter for this property, your code should work, but if you ever use the setValue:forKey: the timestamp won't be updated.

Comment: @iHunter - nothing wrong in settIng another property in a setter. No different to setting it in any other code. If you were setting the _same_ property, you'd be in trouble, but that isn't the case here.

Comment: And using KVO in `NSManagedObject` to observe `self` requires accurate adding/removing in all `awake`/`willTurnIntoFault` methods. Or not in all?

Comment: @AshFurrow - that is not the case. setValue: forKey: just searches for the correctly named accessor method and calls it, as stated in the documentation linked in my answer.

Comment: @jrturton Really? I didn't know that. Then iHunter's original solution, your answer, should work.

Answer (score 0):

In this method, if for any reason you modify the object not as your custom subclass, but as an `NSManagedObject` using `setValue: forKey:` the date will not be updated.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?